# Setting the JAVA_HOME and PATH on MacOS

Tags: java, linux, macos, apache, ant

I want to execute build.xml file using ant. But I am having trouble with recognizing the path for ant and Java. I tried changing the location to the correct location in bashrc as well as tried changing it for current command window using following commands:

```
export path=/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:"$PATH"
echo 'export path=/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:"$PATH"' >> ~/.profile

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:"$PATH"
```

similarly echo to profile for JAVA_HOME
But when I check the paths for these they are not changed. Am I missing something?

```
echo $path
/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin


echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's `PATH` not `path`, and your `JAVA_HOME` is not under "Internet Plug-Ins" - try a `find / -name "javac"`. Also, are you sure that you've installed Java? Finally, after you have set your `JAVA_HOME` correctly do a

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home"
export ANT_HOME="/usr/local/apache-ant"
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin"
```

Check that it works correctly with:

```
java -version
ant -version
```

Then add the `export` lines to `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Yes I am sure I have Installed java. The path for it is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin. The problem I have is that when I am setting the paths the way you have recommended (I am using same commands) I am not able to change the paths.

Comment: java -version       
java version "1.7.0_45"        
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)      
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
echo $PATH
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home//bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
echo $JAVA_HOME 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: How are you launching ant?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44079/discussion-between-elliott-frisch-and-judy)

Comment: Perfect answer, I have been busting my head around this for a long time, but finally it worked

Comment: Using the java_home *command* is a better way to discover the JAVA_HOME. https://confessionsofanagilecoach.blogspot.com/2019/12/setting-jdk-in-sts-4-on-macos.html

Comment: @LanceKind Sadly, that doesn't work with sdkman (which is what I use these days). This example came entirely from the *question*.

Answer (score -1):

1. echo $JAVA_HOME if returns empty(export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home)
2. echo $PATH if returns empty(export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin)
3. export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.3
4. export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
5. mvn --version

ALL SET *******

In case if this doesn't work after this step,

6. vi .profile
7. export PATH={$PATH}:'/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.3/bin/