# Unable to get java command to use correct version of Java

Tags: java

I can't see to set the correct version of Java to use, even though I have set JAVA_HOME correctly:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (5):
    11.0.8, x86_64: "Java SE 11.0.8"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.2, x86_64: "Java SE 11.0.2"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.2, x86_64: "OpenJDK 11.0.2"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_202, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_181, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

How do I get the `java` command to use the correct JDK?

I'm on MacOS Mojave 10.15.6

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x), but it didn't work :-(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting the JAVA\_HOME and PATH on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822101/setting-the-java-home-and-path-on-macos)

Comment: I'm an eejit - I had installed jenv.  https://github.com/jenv/jenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, on OSX, the java command should follow `JAVA_HOME` unless somehow other `java` takes precedence.

You can use `which java` to show where actually the `java` you call according to your `$PATH`.

```
➜ which java
/usr/bin/java

➜ ls -la /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Jun 10 14:33 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

You can see in my machine `/usr/bin/java` actually symlink to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java` which is a kind of proxy to call the right `java` according to `$JAVA_HOME`

So, my suggestion is sorting out your `$PATH` to call `/usr/bin` first. Or just `set export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` to put /usr/bin in the front.